# Pandas: Read specific Excel cell value into a variable

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

**Situation:**

I am using `pandas` to parse in separate Excel (`.xlsx`) sheets from a workbook with the following setup: `Python 3.6.0` and `Anaconda 4.3.1` on `Windows 7 x64.`

**Problem:**

I have been unable to find how to set a variable to a specific Excel sheet cell value e.g. `var = Sheet['A3'].value` from `'Sheet2'` using `pandas`?

**Question:**

Is this possible? If so, how?

**What i have tried:**

I have searched through the `pandas` documentation on `dataframe` and various forums but haven't found an answer to this.

I know i can work around this using `openpyxl` (where i can specify a cell co-ordinate) but I want:

1. To use `pandas` -if possible;
2. Only read in the file once.

I have imported `numpy`, as well as `pandas`, so was able to write:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(filenamewithpath) 

data = xls.parse('Sheet1')
dateinfo2 = str(xls.parse('Sheet2', parse_cols = "A", skiprows = 2, nrows = 1, header = None)[0:1]).split('0\n0')[1].strip()
```

`'Sheet1'` being read into `'data'` is fine as i have a function to collect the range i want.

I am also trying to read in from a separate sheet (`'sheet2'`), the value in cell `"A3"`, and the code i have at present is clunky. It gets the value out as a string, as required, but is in no way pretty. I only want this cell value and as little additional sheet info as possible.

Comment: Clearly one solution would be to read the entire column and assign it to a variable. then extract only the 3rd entry. Unless you have a massive dataset, this is probably the easiest way

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Elaborating on @FLab's comment use something along those lines:

**Edit:**

Updated the answer to correspond to the updated question that asks how to read some sheets at once.
So by providing `sheet_name=None` to `read_excel()` you can read all the sheets at once and pandas return a `dict` of DataFrames, where the keys are the Excel sheet names.

```
import pandas as pd
In [10]:

df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', sheetname=None, header=None)
df
Out[11]:
{u'Sheet1':    0
 0  1
 1  1, u'Sheet2':     0
 0   1
 1   2
 2  10}
In [13]:
data = df["Sheet1"]
secondary_data = df["Sheet2"]
secondary_data.loc[2,0]
Out[13]:
10
```

Alternatively, as noted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41128526/pandas-read-excel-with-multiple-sheets-and-specific-columns), if your Excel file has several sheets you can pass `sheetname` a list of strings, sheet names to parse eg.

```
df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', sheetname=["Sheet1", "Sheet2"], header=None)
```

Credits to user6241235 for digging out the last alternative

Answer (score 14):

Reading an Excel file using Pandas is going to default to a dataframe.  You don't need an entire table, just one cell.  The way I do it is to make that cell a header, for example:

```
# Read Excel and select a single cell (and make it a header for a column)
data = pd.read_excel(filename, 'Sheet2', index_col=None, usecols = "C", header = 10, nrows=0)
```

Will return a "list" of 1 header(s) and no data.  Then isolate that header:

```
# Extract a value from a list (list of headers)
data = data.columns.values[0]
print (data)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use pandas read_excel which has skip_footer argument.
This should work, where skipendrows is number of end rows you want to skip.

```
data = xls.read_excel(filename, 'Sheet2', parse_cols = "A", skipsrows = 2, skip_footer=skipendrows, header =None)
```