# How to loop through excel sheets in python file to calculate the values spread across the sheets?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have one excel file with 3 sheets, each sheet has a set of values within cell A1. How would I loop through the sheets and calculate the values?

I'm new to python and have been struggling to find a solution to this problem.
Thanks

Comment: This question has been already answered. See these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549110/python-loop-through-excel-sheets-place-into-one-df https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544514/pandas-read-specific-excel-cell-value-into-a-variable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-excel-file-using-python/) Code #3 where you can update sheet by looping `sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(x)` and retrieve the cell value `sheet.cell_value(0, 0)`.