# Is there an easy way to "unformat" exotic excel files with pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm currently tasked to build a database using existing excel files. The problem is that the files were generated in such a way that pandas won't be able to read them right just by using `pd.read_excel()`.

Here I built an example of what I call an "exotic" Excel file :

[image: exotic excel file]

So here's my question : What would be the best methodology to deal with that kind of files except by hand (there's like 10.000K files so this is not an option) using python or any other tool/language ?

In advance, thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out this post: [Pandas: Read specific Excel cell value into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544514/pandas-read-specific-excel-cell-value-into-a-variable) you can specify the Sheet and the Cells that you want to import so you only pull in specific regions rather than the whole Sheet/book