# I am trying to read particular excel tab using pandas. But it is reading first tab

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the line of code

```
Df= pandas.read_excel('sample.xlsx', sheet_name='mysheet')
```

It starts reading from sheet1. Any help in this regard, please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Pandas to pd.read\_excel() for multiple worksheets of the same workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook) & [Pandas read_excel() with multiple sheets and specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41128526/pandas-read-excel-with-multiple-sheets-and-specific-columns)

Comment: Tried that way. But still it is reading first tab.

Comment: That's the only way. Make certain you have the correct tab name. Can you share the file?

Comment: My version of pandas is-0.20.1. they have sheetname param there. For later versions they have sheet_name

Comment: That’s pretty old, can’t you update pandas?