# How to concat excels with multiple sheets into one excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlrd

The folder contains at least 20 excels. Each excel contains nine sheets. These excels have same type of sheets (same header but different data). I need to concat these 20 excels sheet by sheet into one excel. And the first two sheets in each excel are instruction. They are skippable. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Example: File A Sheet 3, File B sheet 3, File A sheet 4, File B sheet 4

[image: File A Sheet 3]
[image: File B sheet 3]
[image: File A sheet 4]
[image: File B sheet 4]

So eventually the combination file will be like:

[image: File combination sheet 3]
[image: File combination sheet 4]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import multiple excel files into python pandas and concatenate them into one dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908018/import-multiple-excel-files-into-python-pandas-and-concatenate-them-into-one-dat)

Comment: related [using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook) and [pandas-read-excel-with-multiple-sheets-and-specific-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41128526/pandas-read-excel-with-multiple-sheets-and-specific-columns)

Comment: Have you considered using PowerQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to do something similair a while back:

This code should do the trick for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

collection = {}
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        mysheets = pd.ExcelFile(file)
        mysheetnames = mysheets.sheet_names
        for i in mysheetnames[2:]: #change the 2 in [2:] to change how many sheets you delete
            mydata = pd.read_excel(file, i)
            combi = collection.get(i, [])
            collection[i] = combi + [mydata]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for key in collection:
    myresult = pd.concat(collection.get(key), sort=False)
    myresult.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason this code only create an excel file with every third sheet concat.

Comment: did you copy my code, or did you retype it? It sounds like you forgot the double dots. For example you wrote: `mysheetnames[2]` instead of `mysheetnames[2:]` (the difference is ":")

Comment: Maybe I interperted your question differently, but the problem is that in the excel file one 1 sheet exists? and you want to maintain all the sheetnames you had?

Comment: Yes. The code you gives only create an excel with one sheet (with all the sheets from different excels) but I need each sheet combines separately.  For example, sheet 3 from File A should combine with sheet 3 from File B and so on. So the result file should end up with 9 sheets (in you case 7 sheets without instruction sheet).

Comment: Still the same. Did you try your code yet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235816/discussion-between-anton-van-der-wel-and-buzzmind).